# How to make post category to be seen on the Database?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm unable to see my category in mongodb database.

I want to create a post along with a category, but unfortunately, my category array is Empty.

and the error on my console says... TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_id') on line 24 which is **ids.push(data._id)**

```
exports.createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { file, body } = req;

  const { title, content, categories } = body;
  console.log(categories);

  // check if title is taken
  const findPost = await Post.findOne({ slug: slugify(title.toLowerCase()) });
  if (findPost) return sendError(res, "This Post Title already exists!");

  // get category ids based on category name
  let ids = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    await Category.findOne({
      name: categories[i],
    }).exec((error, data) => {
      if (error) return sendError(res, "Error occurred in Category");
      ids.push(data._id);
    });
  }

  const newPost = await new Post({
    ...body,
    slug: slugify(title),
    categories: ids,
    postedBy: req.user._id,
  });
```

my **Category Controller**

```
exports.createCategory = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  // Check if the Category exists
  const findCategory = await Category.findOne({ name });
  if (findCategory) return sendError(res, "This category already exists!");
  const category = await new Category({
    name,
    slug: slugify(name),
  }).save();
  res.json(category);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have some middleware to set `req.user`.`passport` presumably.

Comment: Have you logged your req.user?

Comment: @drashti-kheni the error is not coming from the user it’s coming from **ids.push(data._id)**

Comment: Are you sure that categories[i] is not undefined or null. If it has some value then verify that category with that name exists in your db.

Comment: @DrashtiKheni I recently created a new category ... I just want a **category** to be on my post when ever I selects one or more...

Comment: what is the log are you getting in `categories[i]`?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni I recently created a new category and it worked very fine ... I just want in a way that **category** should be on my post when ever I selects one or more category while creating a post... it shows both the **error** and the name of the **category** I selected on the console but empty on the **database**.

Comment: Then you are getting this error because your category is not stored to db. So, findOne is returning `null`.

Comment: @DrashtiKheni I guess so

Comment: post the code which creates entry of category to your db

Comment: @DrashtiKheni 

` exports.createCategory = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;
  // Check if the Category exists
  const findCategory = await Category.findOne({ name });
  if (findCategory) return sendError(res, "This category already exists!");
  const category = await new Category({
    name,
    slug: slugify(name),
  }).save();
  res.json(category);
}); `

Comment: please edit in question

Comment: @DrashtiKheni check it out

Comment: are you sure that name is not undefined?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni **name** is defined and working well

Comment: it is not creating entry or creating the entry but has no value?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni you mean the **category** or the **post**??,

if its the **category**, it's creating entry and has value

Comment: Suppose, I create one category with name "education" then is the record inserted in category with name "category" through your controller?

Comment: @DrashtiKheni it doesn't insert category with the name "category", rather it just insert the name of the category you entered

Comment: try once passing the fixed name in `await Category.findOne({name: "education"})` like this

Comment: @DrashtiKheni you mean on **post controller??**

Comment: yes on create post controller

Comment: @DrashtiKheni the same error occurs